# Change Store with Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

In my application, I want to use 2 different stores.  Each store would be selected based on user selection, load it and do stuff with it.

Does Magical Record support this?

When I set up the core data with `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:]`, I create a store name based on the site:

```
- (void)setupDBForSite:(NSString *)site {
    DLog(@"DBStore: %@", [self loadDBStoreForSite:site]);
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:[self loadDBStoreForSite:site]];
}

- (NSString *)loadDBStoreForSite:(NSString *)site {
    NSString *bundleID = (NSString *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@.sqlite", bundleID, site];
}
```

So I had hoped that if I pass in "Site01" it would create a unique store. The next launch, pass in "Site13".  But when I test to see if each store has its own data, both stores contain the same information.

Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Ok, so the issue was with my testing. It looks like it will load the correct store and save to the store fine.

The issue is removing a store and loading a new store.  When I load up the store for "Site01" and then load up store for "Site13", I still only see "Site01" data.  If I load up store for "Site13" first, it has the correct information.

So I need to remove a store and then load up the new store.  But I don't see a method for Magical Record to remove a store.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. Of course, if you do not do anything different based on the store name, the stores will have the same content.

Comment: I do do things different based on the store.  If the user selects "Site01", a `UserDB` entity is created and saved for him.  The next guy selects "Site13", a new `UserDB` entity is created and saved for him. Now both `UserDB` entities show up in both stores.

Comment: Ok, I did some more testing and it looks like the objects are saving to the correct store.  The issues is that I can not switch between the stores.  I load up "Site01" first, check the users in it then I try to load up "Site13" and it displays the users for "Site01".  If I load up store for "Site13" then I try to load up store for "Site01", I get the users for "Site13".

Comment: This description of your woes begs the question if you even need two stores.